# Need an Android Equivalent of ProgressHUD for iOS

Tags: android, kotlin

This is the library I have used in the past for iOS 
https://cocoapods.org/pods/ProgressHUD
I would like to find something similar to it for android studio

I have tried using some libraries on github. the ones I have tried did not work, or i'm just not importing them properly. I haven't actually used a third party library in my android project before so please help me understand how to do this.

I just want a progress HUD that will display a check mark or an X if the answer is right or wrong.

Comment: You can easily do that with out any library .

Comment: Could you please tell me how? I'm new to android studio and I'm used to using a library for this.

Comment: custom alert dialog

Comment: This is a good question that looks like a subjective question! The second paragraph is the objective question: How do I use a third-party library in my Android project? Asking for a recommendation for an equivalent library to one in iOS is subjective and opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this library you can dynamically change right or wrong from progress

[SweetAlert](https://github.com/pedant/sweet-alert-dialog)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I’ll try this out.